# onOptionsItemSelected isn't being called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this called on my Fragment

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "otem: " + item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

What the code above tries to do is to actually go to the previous intent when the back button (home button) at the actionbar is being clicked, instead of displaying the navigation drawer. But it seems everything inside the onOptionsItemSelected in the fragment isn't being executed. (Because if it is, it would display a toast.. I also put a linebreak there) Why?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        if (intent.getStringExtra("intentCaller").equals("expensesRecurring")){
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("tab", "1");
            Fragment fragment = new MenuExpenses();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentExpenses")
                    .commit();
        }

    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));



    }

@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 0:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.menu_home);
                break;
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.menu_analyze);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.menu_expenses);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.menu_income);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        /*
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }*/
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            //((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        int fragments = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (fragments == 1) {
            // make layout invisible since last fragment will be removed
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

NavigationDrawerFragment.java

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 1;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Retain this fragment across configuration changes - added to make sure data in fragment retains after orientation changes
        setRetainInstance(true);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);


    }

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.menu_home),
                        getString(R.string.menu_analyze),
                        getString(R.string.menu_expenses),
                        getString(R.string.menu_income),
                        getString(R.string.menu_moneyJar),
                        getString(R.string.menu_goal),
                        getString(R.string.menu_report),
                        getString(R.string.menu_settings),
                }));
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        ViewGroup mTop = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, mDrawerListView, false);
        mDrawerListView.addHeaderView(mTop, null, false);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                //getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }

        Fragment fragment = null;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (position) {
            case 1:
                fragment = new MenuHome();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentHome");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new MenuAnalyze();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentAnalyze");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new MenuExpensesDaily();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentExpenses");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }
```

MenuExpensesAdd.java (herein lies the problem where its onOptionsItemSelected isn't being called)

```
public class MenuExpensesAdd extends Fragment{

public static MenuExpensesAdd newInstance(int year, int month) {
        MenuExpensesAdd frag = new MenuExpensesAdd();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("year", year);
        args.putInt("month", month);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        initYear = getArguments().getInt("year");
        initMonth = getArguments().getInt("month");
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expenses_add, container, false);

        TextView tbTvTitle = (TextView)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tbTvTitle);
        tbTvTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tbTvTitle.setText("Add New Expenses");
        tbIbSave = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tbIbSave);
        tbIbSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Spinner tbSpnMonth = (Spinner)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tbSpnMonth);
        tbSpnMonth.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Spinner tbSpnYear = (Spinner)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tbSpnYear);
        tbSpnYear.setVisibility(View.GONE);

/* some more codes */
return root;
}

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
    {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


        //fragment specific menu creation
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "otem: " + item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Did you call `this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onCreate()`?

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: @JaredBurrows yes, but still couldn't solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you call `this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onCreate()`?

> Report that this fragment would like to participate in populating the options menu by receiving a call to onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater) and related methods.

**Docs:** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)

**More Reading:** http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar

Comment: yes it's already there. i've edited my question just to show it

Comment: Can you post all of your code? Are you inflating the menu?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what u meant by am I inflating the menu, but since there's plenty of 'inflate' in my codes.. I think yes, I'm inflating the menu.. btw I got the navigationDrawer codes from Android Studio template. And I've added most of my codes above. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: sorry, this actually solves my question... my problem is other thing actually :p

Comment: @imin  I am glad it helped. Sometimes there are these little things in the Android docs that are a little unclear!